# Getting Error database using Prperties file

Tags: java, properties, error-handling

I'm using properties file for Database,and here is mycode:

And I have set my database.prperties file in straight `src` folder.

*here is my code(I'm applying this code in a jsp page):*

```
Properties prop=new Properties();
InputStream inputStream=null;
try{
    inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("database.properties");
    prop.load(inputStream);
}
finally{
    if (inputStream != null) try { inputStream.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
}

String driver=prop.getProperty("driver");
if (driver != null)  
{  
    System.setProperty("driver", driver);  
}
String url = prop.getProperty("url");
String username= prop.getProperty("username");
String password = prop.getProperty("password");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password); // Getting error at this line.
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql = "select * from info;";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
System.out.println(sql);
```

*Here is my properties file :*

```
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/abc
username=crips 
password=drift
```

But I'm getting this error `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root  '@'localhost' (using password: YES)` at line `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);`

Any inputs on this context will appreciated.

Comment: The error seems to be the credentials. Test connection with mysql client and the same credentials from the same PC.

Comment: Make sure there is no other "database.properties" file in the class path.

Comment: The error message says "root" as username, but your properties file says "crips". Did you oversimplify the question? If not, then perhaps you're not editing the properties file you think your code is reading.

Comment: Your question history indicates that you're using JSP/Servlet. Is this code executed in a Servlet based web application? If so, did you rebuild/redeploy/restart the webapp after editing the properties file?

Comment: I changed it in "crips" but still I'm getting this error :( (and that piece of code I found in a tutorial of yours @Balusc :))

Comment: Yes...I using a dynamic web project.

Comment: Do you *actually* get the error *"Access denied for user 'crips'@'localhost'"*? Well, apparently the given user isn't been granted access, exactly as the exception message tells. You'd need to issue the `GRANT` command.

Comment: The error I'm getting is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'crips  '@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'crips'@'localhost'
```

This means that the given user isn't been granted access to the database which you're attempting to connect. You'd need to issue the following SQL command with MySQL admin rights:

```sql
GRANT ALL ON abc.* TO 'crips'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'drift';
```

Note that the user name and password are case sensitive.

Also note that this has after all nothing to do with reading properties files. You'd have exactly the same problem when supplying username/password/database as hardcoded string variables.

Comment: I did this change but showing the same error    java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'crips '@'localhost',I found that an extra space is there in crips,..do I to need reset this grant permission ?

Comment: So there's a space behind "crips" in the properties file? Remove it. To prevent this in the future, issue `trim()` after obtaining the (non-null) property value. An utility method may be helpful on this. See also [this DAO tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html).

Comment: Now getting this error **java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost/abc** any inputs

Comment: Perhaps you changed a bit too much? This part has worked fine before (without a driver it's namely not possible to create a connection). This particular exception means that the driver isn't been loaded, or that the JDBC connection URL isn't recognized by any of the loaded drivers. Perhaps a typo in JDBC connection URL? It should start with `jdbc:mysql:` in order to be recognized by the MySQL JDBC driver.

Comment: IT's working,...Just I have to restart the server :) :) + thanks to you + your contribution for this community & Big fan of yours(the way you code..)

Comment: 1 more thing I want to ask,in my project when I'm running a jsp page it's showing the path "http://localhost:8080/Info/jsp/Info.jsp"(Info is my Projct name),I want make it as default(landing) page which can run in http://localhost:8080/ how can I acheive this..... any inputs

Comment: sorry to I'm calling you in this way,..I'm getting an error kindly if you take a look of it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606815/getting-null-value-from-attribute/13607523#13607523