# Getting Null value from attribute

Tags: java, servlets, null

In the Dynamic web application I facing some issues,so I'm posting my code:

Here is my controller(servlet):

```
        String select = request.getParameter("select");  // getting proper value
        String search = request.getParameter("search");  // getting proper value
        request.setAttribute("select", select);
        request.setAttribute("search", search);
        System.out.println("Select : "+select+" Search : "+search);

            int page = 1;
            int recordsPerPage = 20;
            if(request.getParameter("page") != null)
                page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
            SearchDAO searchDAO=new SearchDAO();
            List<User> list=searchDAO.searchAllUsers((page-1)*recordsPerPage,recordsPerPage,select,search);
            int noOfRecords = searchDAO.getNoOfRecords();
                    System.out.println("4> NoOfRecords : "+noOfRecords);
            int noOfPages = (int) Math.ceil(noOfRecords * 1.0 / recordsPerPage);
                    System.out.println("5> NoOfPages : "+noOfPages);
            request.setAttribute("searchList", list);
            System.out.println("6> List : "+list);
            request.setAttribute("noOfPages", noOfPages); // Getting null value, 0
            request.setAttribute("currentPage", page); // Getting null value, 0
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/Securex_Anti_Theft_SearchUserList.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);
```

And here is my DAO (simple java class):

```
public class SearchDAO {
private int noOfRecords;
Connection connection;
Statement stmt;

    public List<User> searchAllUsers(int offset ,int noOfRecords,String select,String search){
    private static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException{
    Connection con = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
    return con;  //ConnectionFactory is class for making the connection to DB.
}
     String query="select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from info where '"+select+
"' like '%"+search+"%' order by serialNo asc limit 
" + offset + " , " + noOfRecords;

    List<User> list1 = new ArrayList<User>();
    User user1=null;

    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("1> :"+rs);
        while(rs.next()){
        user1=new User();
        user1.setSerial(rs.getInt(1));
        System.out.println("I'm inside a loop");
        user1.setName(rs.getString(2));
        user1.setEmail(rs.getString(3));
        list1.add(user1);
        }

        rs.close();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
        System.out.println("2> :" +rs);
        if(rs.next())
            this.noOfRecords = rs.getInt(1); 
           System.out.println("3> :" +this.noOfRecords);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally
    {
        try {
            if(stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
            if(connection != null)
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return list1;

}

public int getNoOfRecords() {
    return noOfRecords;
}
}
```

And the Output is :

```
1> :com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@1af8502
2> :com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@455aa8
3> :0
4> NoOfRecords : 0
5> NoOfPages : 0
6> List : []
```

I have same same servlet and class for select all users,and that's working properly,bbut getting null value from here.Even ResultSet returns value i.e. com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@88d319,but unable fetch the value from DAO to servlet.

Getting null value from `//` attributes,To me everything should be going fine but still getting null value,feel free to point out my mistake,If I have done anything

Comment: Are you sure, that your DAO returns not empty result?

Comment: ResultSet returns value i.e. com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@88d319,but unable fetch the value from DAO to servlet

Comment: in your Dao class, why the method `searchAllUsers` and `getConnection` are nested?

Comment: I asked about list of Users, ResultSet could be simply empty. You need to check your SQL in this case.

Comment: searchAllUsers -> returns a list of user and getConnection-> using ConnectionFactory class to connect with DB,.... & nested means ?

Comment: @mudalov It's working in mysql console,so I have written it.

Comment: Can you post output of your code too? (i.e. the sysouts)

Comment: @sgp15 yes I have updated with output.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your DAO returns empty list. All other code looks fine. So, first of all I would check this call

```
searchDAO.searchAllUsers((page-1)*recordsPerPage,recordsPerPage,select,search);
```

What is the value for `page` variable? Other parameters? Please log the **query** after:

```
 String query="select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from info where '"+select+
"' like '%"+search+"%' order by serialNo asc limit 
" + offset + " , " + noOfRecords;
```

and run it separately against DB, it should give you an answer.

Comment: I have run it numerable times in mysql console,and it's giving right answer, and I have updated my Ques. :(

Comment: As page equivalent to offset,so i assign it to 1,so the limit becomes 0,noOfRecords.

Comment: Empty result, so next returns false

Comment: so what would be the best thing for me ?

Comment: Check result query (string), then try to run the same query against DB using some tool. If it returns empty result, then you just need to realize why.